# Condition on a dataframe to create a new dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe as below.

```
    id type  value     Date name
0  111    a    100  2018/11   x1
1  112    b    200  2018/12   x2
2  113    a    300  2018/08   x3
3  113    a    200  2018/08   x4
4  114    a    300  2017/12   x4
5  114    a    500  2018/12   x5
6  114    b    500  2018/12   x5
```

I want a create a dataframe based on 4 conditions.

1. if id unique and type != b then take line and add column case1
2. if id unique and type = b then take line if name unique and add column case2
3. if id not unique and type != b then
   aggregate line with same date, summing value, add column case3
4. if id not unique and type = b then
   aggregate line with same date , summing value ignoring rows with type b, add column case4

The new dataframe will be as follow

```
    id type  value     Date   case
0  111    a    100  2018/11  case1
1  112    b    200  2018/12  case2
2  113    a    500  2018/08  case3
3  114    a    300  2017/12  case4
4  114    b    500  2018/12  case4
```

I have tried to create the column 'case' as my first step :

> for i in df.id.unique():
>
> ```
> if 'b' in df.Type:
>
>     df['Case']= 'case 1'
>
> else:
>
>     df['Case']= 'case 2' else:
> ```
>
> else:
>
> ```
> if 'b' in df.Type:
>
>     df['Case']= 'case 3'
>
> else:
>
>     df['Case']= 'case 4'
> ```

Im new to pandas manipulation so advices will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# groupby and add group sizes
df['id_count'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size')

# conditions for np.select
conditions = [
    (df['id_count'].eq(1) & df['type'].ne('b')),
    (df['id_count'].eq(1) & df['type'].eq('b')),
    (df['id_count'].ne(1) & df['type'].ne('b')),
    (df['id_count'].ne(1) & df['type'].eq('b'))]
# choices for np.select
choices = ['case1', 'case2', 'case3', 'case4']
# Add case column
df['case'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=None)

# next grouping
grouping = ['id', 'type', 'Date', 'case']
# replace value column
df['value'] = df.groupby(grouping)['value'].transform('sum')

# drop duplicate rows
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=grouping, keep='first')
# remove extra columns
df = df.drop(['name', 'id_count'], axis='columns')
```

---

#### Step by step

First of all you can create a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) of the `id` column, like so:

```
gb = df.groupby('id')
```

Then you can use this to count how many times an `id` occurs:

```
df['id_count'] = gb['id'].transform('size')
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
    id type  value     Date name  id_count
0  111    a    100  2018/11   x1         1
1  112    b    200  2018/12   x2         1
2  113    a    300  2018/08   x3         2
3  113    a    200  2018/08   x4         2
4  114    a    300  2017/12   x4         3
5  114    a    500  2018/12   x5         3
6  114    b    500  2018/12   x5         3
```

Now you can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to make your conditions:

```
conditions = [
    (df['id_count'].eq(1) & df['type'].ne('b')),
    (df['id_count'].eq(1) & df['type'].eq('b')),
    (df['id_count'].ne(1) & df['type'].ne('b')),
    (df['id_count'].ne(1) & df['type'].eq('b'))]
choices = ['case1', 'case2', 'case3', 'case4']
df['case'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=None)
```

Resulting in:

```
    id type  value     Date name  id_count   case
0  111    a    100  2018/11   x1         1  case1
1  112    b    200  2018/12   x2         1  case2
2  113    a    300  2018/08   x3         2  case3
3  113    a    200  2018/08   x4         2  case3
4  114    a    300  2017/12   x4         3  case3
5  114    a    500  2018/12   x5         3  case3
6  114    b    500  2018/12   x5         3  case4
```

Create another groupby using `grouping` (a list of columns); then `sum` the `value` column in these groups, replacing the `value` column.

```
grouping = ['id', 'type', 'Date', 'case']
df['value'] = df.groupby(grouping)['value'].transform('sum')
```

Resulting in:

```
    id type  value     Date name  id_count   case
0  111    a    100  2018/11   x1         1  case1
1  112    b    200  2018/12   x2         1  case2
2  113    a    500  2018/08   x3         2  case3
3  113    a    500  2018/08   x4         2  case3
4  114    a    300  2017/12   x4         3  case3
5  114    a    500  2018/12   x5         3  case3
6  114    b    500  2018/12   x5         3  case4
```

Finally, [`drop-duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) using the `grouping` list from before:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=grouping, keep='first')
```

Giving:

```
    id type  value     Date name  id_count   case
0  111    a    100  2018/11   x1         1  case1
1  112    b    200  2018/12   x2         1  case2
2  113    a    500  2018/08   x3         2  case3
4  114    a    300  2017/12   x4         3  case3
6  114    b    500  2018/12   x5         3  case4
```

You can remove the extra column using [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop(['name', 'id_count'], axis='columns')
```